# Source-map must be turned on for println to work?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

This is really strange. I had this in my project.clj:

```clj
  :cljsbuild
  {:builds
   [{:id "async-tues-id"
     :source-paths ["src/async_tues/cljs"]
     :compiler {:optimizations :none
                :pretty-print false
                :output-dir "resources/compiler/"
                :output-to "resources/main.js"}}]}
```

Note that source-map is not turned on here.

Then I had this in my cljs file:

```clj
(ns tues.page)
(enable-console-print!)

(println "hello from cljs!")

(println "hi from page.js")
```

After `lein cljsbuild` the browser prints to *empty* lines to the console. I'd add more `println` statement and it executes them... but there is no text.

I then added this to the project.clj:

```clj
            :source-map true
```

After new compilation, the printlns show up with the actual text as desired! Now why would source-map have anything to do with the actual functionality of `println`??

Comment: That's pretty weird, try posting a git project's URL, otherwise it'll be hard to reproduce.

Comment: @Joaquin so you are saying this is definitely *not* normal behavior? or is println functionality attached to source-map behavior?

Comment: It should work just fine with the enable-console-print!. It is definitely not normal. Try with `(.log js/console "hi")` and see if it works.

Comment: specify clojure, clojurescript versions. Add github project url which can be used to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like "lein new reagent my-project" to create your project, you'll see something like this inside of prod/cljs/my-project/prod.cljs.

```
(ns reagent.prod
  (:require [reagent.core :as core]))

;;ignore println statements in prod
(set! *print-fn* (fn [& _]))

(core/init!)
```

To specify no :optimizations, I believe the correct value is :whitespace, not :none. :simple and :advanced are also valid (always use :advanced in production).

It's a bit far fetched, but perhaps turning on :source-maps caused :optimizations to default to a more logical non-production value (since :none is not valid), which somehow caused the overriding of *print-fn* to not occur.